# How Magento 2.1.x minicart renders items, image and price

Tags: magento-2.1

How Magento 2 minicart renders items, image and price.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an illustrated version of Magento 2.1.x minicart rendering. Please let me know if something is missing and need to be added or updated.

[image]

Comment: Awesome.. Where did you get this flow diagram? or how did you create this?