# How does the minicart takes cart items?

Tags: magento2, products

Hoes does the cart items get inside minicart? More precisely inside minicart.js there is a variable cart that has a field items that contains the same products as the cart. How does that cart variable gets populated?

I ask this because i have another table that contains reserved products and i'd like to know how can i have inside minicart.js a variable of my own that has items from my custom table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this diagram will help you to understand the situation,

[image]

Credit: [Asrar](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50597/asrar)

Source: [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195353/how-magento-2-1-x-minicart-renders-items-image-and-price)

Comment: Thanks man!! the part with the config method was what i was looking for